# How to delete node installed by brew completely?

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I have a problem with uninstalling 'node' with brew. 
When I used

```
brew uninstall node
```

, it showed:

```
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.8.0... (3,076 files, 39.9MB)
```

; but when I commanded:

```
node -v
```

, there is still

```
v6.9.4
```

When I tried to use `brew uninstall node` again, it showed:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node
```

I think I installed `node` package before, and today I used a wrong command:

```
brew install nodejs
```

while I actually wanted to install node. And then I found I was wrong, so I also uninstalled nodejs in the same way. But `node` package with lower version is still there. Anybody knows why and can help me delete it completely and reinstall?

Comment: What's the output of 'ls -la $(which node)'?

Comment: Thanks Paul, it shows: -rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel  30640720 Jan  5 16:15 /usr/local/bin/node ; btw, is it correct to reply you here? Idk where I can click reply button to your comments lol

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you may have installed node via another method in the past.

If you do

```
$ ls -la $(which node)
```

It should tell you where it's installed (and if that's symlinked to another location or not).

Removing that binary is part of the thing, the other thing you'll want to do is remove the root npm and the node_modules folder.

Find npm the same way as you found the node binary, but the root node_modules folder is probably either under /usr/local/lib but might be elsewhere; you can check `npm config ls -l` to get a list of all the settings of npm, which will tell you what directories to look in are.

Comment: Thank you Paul, with that command, it shows: -rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel  30640720 Jan  5 16:15 /usr/local/bin/node